# Mesh looks OK in wireframe but shading is distorted

Tags: 3d-view, shaders

Imported an OBJ file in Blender 2.91.0. Mesh looks OK in wireframe view and exports OK to other s/ware but weird in all shaded viewport views. Example included shows object Shaded Flat. All surfaces are concaved. A recurring issue for me. Checked normals are OK, checked no modifiers on the object apart from a collision modifier. Searched the net.  Any ideas?

[image: Flat Shaded]

[image: Wireframe]

Comment: That's interestingly screwed up.  On properties/object data/geometry, click clear custom normals.  If it doesn't help you out, link a file.

Comment: OK that fixed it! Thanks Nathan. Custom normals would have come across in the OBJ file?

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by Nathan. Solution was to clear custom split normals in Object Data Properties/Geometry Data.